# How to get non cached result from a cacheable method?

Tags: spring, spring-cache

Let's say a business method annotated with [`@Cacheable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html).

```java
@Component
class Some {

    @Cacheable
    public Some getSome() {
    }
}
```

Now can any caller conditionally request non cached result, as if the method is not annotated with [`@Cacheable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) at all, without evicting the cache nor using a separated method?

```java
    void doOther() {
        // How can I get non-cached live result from some#getSome()
    }

    @Autowired
    private Some some;
```

I found [`condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#condition--) and [`unless`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#unless--), but those are not for my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching mechanism through `@Cacheable` is achieved by using proxies. To ignore caching you should unwrap proxy into real target object, and directly invoke its unwrapped method:

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;

...

@Autowired
private Some some;

void doOther() {
    Some unproxied = (Some) AopProxyUtils.getSingletonTarget(some);
    Some noncached = unproxied.getSome();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Neat! Neat! Neat!